# Get all overlapping elements in live aquea

Tags: c#

Is it possible to get all overlapping elements in live aquea? I caluclate it trough vectors. Is there a more elegant way?

```
var allOverlapping = Collection<ElementClass>.Overlapping();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. Just push all elements inside LQList. You can call `Intersect`on it.

```
var allIntersecting = LQList<ElementClass>.Intersect();
```